# Как на SQL написать сложный запрос с группировкой?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Подскажите как составить запрос. Сам пока только начинаю осваивать базы данных и нет знаний и опыта.

Есть табличка с диалогами, у нее есть dialog_id, start_agent_id, end_agent_id (идентификатор агента стартовавшего и закрывшего диалог).

Я хочу с базы получить данные в формате сколько диалогов клиент обработал (start_agent_id = end_agent_id) и сколько пропустил (start_agent_id != end_agent_id) ну и сгруппировать все это дело конечно по ФИО агента

Сейчас у меня получается, что я могу только либо собрать все пропущенные, либо все обработанные

```
select 
  count (cd.dialog_id) cnt,
  ca.fullname
from chat_dialog cd
  inner join chat_agent ca on ca.agent_id = cd.start_agent_id
where start_agent_id = end_agent_id 
group by ca.fullname
order by ca.fullname asc
```

Можно конечно 2 простых запроса кинуть и на Node потом укомплектовать данные из 2-х запросов, но хотелось бы это все-таки сразу и базы получить.

Как еще добавить один столбец, но чтобы там уже отбор был по условию `where start_agent_id = end_agent_id`

```
cnt | fullname
51  |   user_1
34  |   user_2
```

Comment: Уберите where. А вместо count() используйте `sum(case when start_agent_id = end_agent_id then 1 else 0 end)` ну и вторую такую же колонку с неравенством. В общем складываем единицы когда условие сходится

Comment: Теоретически (не знаю подробностей предметной области) есть же и незакрытые диалоги? типа у которых end_agent_id IS NULL... если да - не забудьте подумать о судьбе количества таких диалогов - а то баланс не сойдётся...

Comment: @Akina, как правило, они быстро закрываются, но думаю учесть точно стоит

Comment: В общем случае можно сделать `join` через вложенные запросы: `select * from (select ...) t1 left join (select ... ) t2 ON t1.field = t2.field`. Решение хоть и универсальное, но тяжелое и в вашем случае стоит использовать условия в выборке как написал @Mike.

Comment: @AlexKrass, в данном случае, решение которое подсказал Mike выглядит проще и по крайней мере мне пока с моим уровнем знаний более понятey, но думаю чуть позже, нужно будет попробовать ваше решение, потому что там нужно будет еще данных к этой таблице примешать

Answer (score 2):

С Postgres 9.4+ можно сделать так:

```sql
SELECT
  count(cd.dialog_id) FILTER (WHERE cd.start_agent_id = cd.end_agent_id) processed,
  count(cd.dialog_id) FILTER (WHERE cd.start_agent_id <> cd.end_agent_id OR cd.end_agent_id IS NULL) skipped,
  ca.fullname
FROM chat_dialog cd
  JOIN chat_agent ca ON ca.agent_id = cd.start_agent_id
GROUP BY ca.fullname
ORDER BY ca.fullname
```

При использовании Postgres < 9.4:

```
SELECT
  count(CASE WHEN cd.start_agent_id = cd.end_agent_id THEN cd.dialog_id END) processed,
  count(CASE WHEN cd.start_agent_id <> cd.end_agent_id OR cd.end_agent_id IS NULL THEN cd.dialog_id END) skipped,
  ca.fullname
FROM chat_dialog cd
  JOIN chat_agent ca ON ca.agent_id = cd.start_agent_id
GROUP BY ca.fullname
ORDER BY ca.fullname
```